# Is it a good idea to train word2vec with unsupervised crawled text from the Web?

Tags: java, machine-learning, word2vec

I would like to know if it is, in general, a good idea to train word2vec with text automatically crawled from the Web. In the examples you can find on the Web, the algorithm is always trained with text of high quality (correct sentences, correct punctuation marks, no strange words, and so on).

However, when automatically crawling the Web, the quality of the raw text is not going to be so high. On the other hand, the compilation of the text for training can be done automatically and we do not need to spend time on it.

Answer (score 3):

To complement others answers, I would say that it really depends on what you want to do with the word vectors (output of word2Vec) after their creation :
if your intention is to use them to do some natural language processing (clustering, sentiment analysis,...) on text of bad quality (let's say forums content or tweets where oral language, abreviations, non correct phrases,...) it might be relevant. On the other side, if your model will later be used to process text of high quality, it is probably a bad idea.

Word2Vec algorithm tends to produce better accuracy with increasing amount of (good) text. My current approach is to use a dump of wikipedia, and to complement it with content retrieved by crawling.

As a first way to get better quality text, my crawler uses a white list of website of good quality (news website, government and administration, universities,...), and will thus retrieve content from this website only.

I still keep some bad text to have at least some representation of oral language, conversations, slang,... Depending on the usage, it might prove useful.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't do that. The quality of data is always an important fact. 
I would pre-process/filter data first. 
On the other hand, you can ingest all data and leave unclear words out to treat them later or leave it as not valid data. You can launch a batch process to clean data first so I don't think automatization is a problem. You can even ingest it/filter in real time (streaming) from the crawler and then start training your word2vec as soon as data is filtered.
Sorry if my answer is too vague. Maybe if you tell us how you are approaching it or we can see some non-quality register the answer can be more accurate.

Maybe this link can give you some clues: http://chapeau.freevariable.com/2015/12/using-word2vec-on-log-messages.html

Comment: Do you know how word2vec treats line breaks. For example articles from a blog as one article per line vs. "as is" with line breaks?